# How to solve error failed to open stream: HTTP request failed while using file_get_contents in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I tried to use `file_get_contents()` function in my project developed in Laravel. I used this function to send SMS in bulk and retrive its response.

First I encoded URL with sms providers specification and tested with five users and it worked well.  But after that I tried to send SMS to 60 mobile numbers through this URL by using `file_get_contents()` function, it shows error `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed`.  I have gone through related doubts in stack over flow, but that solutions are not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's better if you show the code and explain the snippets instead.

Comment: whatever you're using as the url is incorrect, or that url isn't reachable from your server. that's something YOU'LL have to debug.

Comment: Please check that in URL it is an http:// or https:// So, many people doing such mistake.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right, you are trying to send data via `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Hi, $publishmsgnw = str_replace(' ', '%20', $publishmsg);
  $publishmsgstr = implode("", $publishmsgnw);
  $url = 'http://example.in/Messaging.svc/mtsms?data=<SmsQueue><Account><User>ABCD</User><Password>12345</Password></Account><MessageData><SenderId>MYMSG</SenderId><Gwid>2</Gwid><DataCoding>0</DataCoding></MessageData><Messages>'.$publishmsgstr.'</Messages></SmsQueue>';
  $response = file_get_contents($url);  this is a part of code i am using to sens sms. $publishmsg is an message format array as following <Message><Number>'.$parent->pmobile.'</Number><Text>'.$resultmsg.'</Text></Message>

Comment: @AlanMachadoThis methode works well for sending four or five people. But If I tried to send sms to around 50 people then it shows error 404